# How do we compare two JSON objects in mule4 using Dataweave?

Tags: dataweave

I need to compare two JSON objects based on a field value in the first JSON object,
that field value will be a field in another JSON object

for better clarity of my question the JSON objects are below

1. first JSON object where the field called "Name" has the value "company_name"

```
{

 "Name": "company_name",

 "BillingStreet": "street"

}
```

2. second JSON object where the field called "company_name". this field is actually is the compare field to the first JSON field Called "Name".

```
{

"id": 53411170,

"entity_type": "company",

"company_name": "Test",

"xyz": "123",

}
```

I want the desired output as below

```
{

"Name" : "Test"

}

Thanks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this. Try with this and maybe you can optimize it.

**Payload**

```
{

 "Name": "company_name",
 "BillingStreet": "streets"
}
```

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var inp = {
"id": 53411170,
"entity_type": "company",
"company_name": "Test",
"street": "abc"
}

---
payload mapObject {
    (($$) : inp[$]) if (inp[$] != null)
}
```

**Output**

```
{
  "Name": "Test"
}
```